# Finding all users who are local admin on domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

In our windows 2003 domain there are a few computers where domain users are member of the local administrator group.

I am looking for the best way to create a list of all the computers where this is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this one successfully. [Powershell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/190aadd4-01ef-4e26-8ff0-9862439f5328)

Answer (score 4):

After a quick search I found this:
http://briandesmond.com/blog/script-to-collect-local-administrators-membership-from-list-of-machines/

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923.aspx) will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free GUI tool: **"Get Local Admins GUI"**

Source: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/02/windows-buscar-administradores-locales.html

This tool permits to see the members of the local Administrators group on multiple remote computers. You can export results to CSV and import a machine list from Active Directory OU.